# Laravel DataTable implementation

Tags: jquery, laravel, bootstrap-4, datatable, datatables

I need to implement DataTable so my tables in my Laravel project can be something like this:

[image: Image 1]

At the moment all my tables are "formed" and look like this:

[image: Image 2]

Answer (score 0):

it's not about Laravel. Your problem about with your jquery datatable plugin. Look for your datatable documents.

Comment: What do you mean? I'm having a very hard moment trying to figure this out. I have installed DataTables via terminal in my laravel project but I don't know how to implement them...

Answer (score 0):

You can see the [datatable documentation](https://datatables.net/).

You can see the datatable as you want.
[image: Standard Datatable]

Hope to helpful!

Comment: I have tried several stuff but I'm afraid to mess with my Controllers and my project suddenly stops working

Comment: I think that is not related with datatable